# UI Navigation Technique

Tags: iphone, uiview

In my iPhone application I have 2 stage registration view .I have 3 views lets call them **A,B,C** .If I navigate through **A->B->C** and then if I want to go back  to **view A** from **view C** Which is the best possible solution?

simply saying **A -> B -> C** from **C -> A**

Is it best practice to use add subview ?

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems a little confusion you going **A->B->C** and you want go back from **A to C** ,i think it would be **C to A.**
This can be done by

```
 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController C, assuming that A is the `rootViewController` for the `UINavigationController`

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Otherwise, pass a reference to your A view controller through the view stack as you push new views. Then in your view controller C use:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController: A animated: YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided your A is root view controller, do this

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If A is not your root view controller, do this

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index_of_A_viewcontorller] animated:YES];
```

If you dont know at what index is your A view then u can *print* the **self.navigationController.viewControllers** and see it yourself

```
NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController.viewControllers);
```